# Unable to create application factory of class org.apache.wicket.spring.SpringWebApplicationFactory

Tags: java, spring, maven-2, maven, wicket

```
org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebApplicationFactoryCreationException: Unable to create application factory of class org.apache.wicket.spring.SpringWebApplicationFactory
        at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.getApplicationFactory(WicketFilter.java:228)
        at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.init(WicketFilter.java:271)
        at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.init(WicketFilter.java:252)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:713)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.java:115)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:132)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:454)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:396)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyRunMojo.execute(AbstractJettyRunMojo.java:210)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6RunMojo.execute(Jetty6RunMojo.java:184)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:195)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:140)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:314)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:151)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:445)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:168)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:132)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
2010-12-28 14:51:46.213:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
```

I am using Wicket 1.5 M3, Spring 3.0 and i am getting this error. Below is my Web.xml config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
     version="2.4">

    <display-name>mysticpaste</display-name>

     <!--  
          There are three means to configure Wickets configuration mode and they are
          tested in the order given. 
          1) A system property: -Dwicket.configuration
          2) servlet specific <init-param>
          3) context specific <context-param>
          The value might be either "development" (reloading when templates change)
          or "deployment". If no configuration is found, "development" is the default.
    -->



    <filter>
            <filter-name>wicket.mysticpaste</filter-name>
            <filter-class>
                org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter
                </filter-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>applicationFactoryClassName</param-name>
                <param-value>org.apache.wicket.spring.SpringWebApplicationFactory</param-value>
            </init-param>
    </filter>

        <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:com/mysticcoders/mysticpaste/spring/application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
          org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

     <filter>
        <filter-name>wicket.session</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.servlet.WicketSessionFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>filterName</param-name>
            <param-value>wicket.mysticpaste</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>wicket.session</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

   <filter>
       <filter-name>open.hibernate.session.in.view</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <!-- Important! This filter mapping must come before Wicket's! -->
    <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>open.hibernate.session.in.view</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>



</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you declared/annotated your web application as a Spring bean? It's required before Wicket can find your web application through Spring. (Also see: [SpringWebApplicationFactory](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/spring/SpringWebApplicationFactory.html))